Is it possible to accumulate platform tokens on online survey platforms in Germany in one year that can be cashed out tax-free in the next year
In Germany it's possible to take part in online surveys using sites like Toluna,
Meinungsstudie.de ...
In Germany it's also possible to earn up to 410 Euros per year tax-free.
So one can make up to 410 Euros from online surveys without paying taxes.
Now it's not really clear, "when" is this money considered to be "made"?
Many of these sites don't immediately transfer money made from online surveys to
a valid bank account but rather use some kind of "platform token" or "platform
currency" that can be used in exchange for gift cards (that can be redeemed at
Amazon etc.), or to cash out the money to said bank account (Paypal also seems
to be used quite often).
So this seems to work like a credit item, doesn't it?
Since we can earn up to 410 Euros per year tax-free, is it actually possible to
do preparatory work in one year?
Example
Eg., person A makes 400 Euros in year 2023 from online surveys which he then
cashes out tax-free in the same year (2023). Still in year 2023, he collects
platform tokens worth 100 Euros.
Then, in year 2024, he cashes out these platform tokens he accumulated in back
in year 2023 (worth 100 Euros).
Would these 100 Eurors be subject to taxation in year 2023 (since the platform
tokens have been made in 2023) or is this money subject to taxation in year 2024?

Generally, if these tokens are redeemable in cash - they count as cash for tax purposes. Barter exchange doesn't allow deferring taxes, it's just conversion of assets.
